# Driving an LED with a low amplitude square wave as an input of MOSFET switch

Tags: led, constant-current

I am trying to drive an LED with a square wave.
I've made a circuit like below:

The problem is, an equiment can generates a square wave with a limited amplitude up to 1.7 V.

After some experiments, I realized that the LED `D1` becomes bright enought if the amplitude of `V1` is higher than 2.5 V.

I guess this is because a drain current `I_D` isn't large enough according to the transfer characteristics of `M1`, `STD12NF06L-1`.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDAOMN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think `D1` can be brighter if BJT is used even though the amplitude of `V1` is not high enough:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAitTX.png)</sup>

The circuit right above is a circuit I imagined by some googling. (I have little knowledge about circuits)

By making a such circuit, a square wave `V1` can only act as a trigger signal, and the LED `D1` can receive enough current by the BJT.

**In short,** I want to provide a sufficient current to `D1` no matter how the amplitude of `V1` is large or small.

1. Is what I think ---using BJT to provide a constant current--- correct?
2. If the first is right, which BJT `Q1` and resistor `R3` can be used?
3. If the first is wrong, can it be solved by using voltage amplifier near `V1`?

PS: My final goal is to drive the LED with frequnecy up to 2-4 MHz. Are parts and circuit I am using too slow to achieve such a goal?

Comment: In the first circuit move R2, the current limiting resistor, so that it above the FET... You still may not have enough voltage to turn the fet on... so maybe replace it with an npn bipolar.  Get that working and then do the MHz drive.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold You really ought to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jeon That BJT modification would just waste power and do nothing useful at all, if done as shown in your second schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00002633.pdf) of your MOSFET, figure 5 "Transfer characteristics" at page 5. Your transistor only starts conducting significant current when Vgs (the gate to source voltage) reaches 2 volts. This is called the **treshold voltage**. As the amplitude of your signal is quite low, Vgs never reaches a voltage high enough and your MOSFET fails to conduct enough current for the LED to turn on properly.

In order to fully turn on the led, your circuit only needs a small modification: you need to *add a DC bias to the gate of the MOSFET*. This can be accomplished with a dc blocking capacitor and a voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXxyFF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 47kΩ and 33kΩ resistors form a voltage divider, maintaining the gate of the MOSFET at an average voltage of 5V * 33kΩ / (47kΩ + 33kΩ) = 2,06V relative to the source. Your signal is AC coupled to the gate, causing Vgs to go above and below the threshold voltage and thus switch the state of the LED.

If you need to connect a lower impedance load to the MOSFET (that draws a current higher than a couple hundred milliamperes when on), you need to add a proper [gate driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_driver) between your signal and the gate of the tansistor.

Comment: A couple of questions, 1. is it safe to use electrolytic capacitor for `C1`? 2. Does a value `1uF` change when a frequency of a square wave changes?

Comment: Raising the frequency allows you to use a smaller capacitor, but a cap too small will form a crude filter with the resistors and the parasitic characteristics of the MOSFET, leading to distortion. An electrolytic capacitor will do just fine, however its parasitic series inductance can become a problem at high frequencies (> 1MHz).

Comment: You have to be 100% sure about the gate threshold of the mosfet for this to work. Moreover, this would not be able to keep the led on for more than the time constant of the RC circuit, here about 20ms. Depending on the application, this might not be acceptable.

Comment: Yes, if you want to drive the LED at anything but 50% average duty cycle, you need DC coupling. DC coupling can be accomplished for example with a [opamp differential amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html). If you want to drive a low impedance load you also need a gate driver. This can get quite complex, especially at frequencies above 1MHz.

Answer (score 1):

If this is pretty much your idea of current level, I would strongly suggest scrapping that power MOSFET which actually takes more current to drive than the LED even at 2MHz.

Get yourself a single gate buffer such as the TC7SZ17F which can drive 32mA with a 5V supply and drop less than 700mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzWmYT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust the value of C1 to maximize the frequency response. Make sure you have a good bypass capacitor (1uF in parallel with 10uF would be good) near the gate power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking with your 1st circuit but change R2 to the drain side because in your current configuration any current going through R2 generates a voltage across it and it causes a negative feedback because Vgs voltage is decreased and therefore the MOSFET goes less on than it was and your LED not as bright as it should but if you change R2 to the drain side that negative feedback doesn't occur any more.